# how to compute p-value from Fisher's Z transformation?

Tags: r, p-value

I'm having a list of Pearson's correlation coefficients (r). Then, I performed the Fisher's Z transformation using the formula: z = 1/2 ln(1+r/1-r). Now, I want to compute corresponding p-values for each identified z score. After referring to Google, I detect a formula to compute p-value (two-sided) like:
p-value = 2*pnorm(-abs(z))
Is it correct?
Also, Can anyone give me a formula to compute 95% confidence intervals of z score?

Btw, I'm using R to handle all of them! Thanks bunch in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `library(psych)` and function `fisherz()`

Comment: Many thanks! I forgot to say thank you at that time! Your solution is great!